# EE2: How to use the {template_group} variable or how to get value of template group in a template?

Tags: global-variables

I am confused about the usage of the mentioned variable. It should be plain and simple... but for some reason, I can't get it to work.

Documentation link for EE3: https://docs.expressionengine.com/v3/templates/globals/single_variables.html#template-group

**I want to use the template group name in my templates, is there any way to make this possible in EE2?**

Comment: It actually is very simple. Suppose you have a template group named `about.group` and in your index file of that group, if you place `{template_group}` variable, It will give you result "about". Its working for me.

Comment: I tried the same several times on several templates with no luck. The thing is, that the other global variables are working fine...

Comment: what is your EE version?

Comment: Ufff.... it is 2.10.3 
We have several sites, I must have confused with the ones on version 3.
So, I guess there is no easy way of getting the group name on this version.. right?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing up versions of EE.

`{template_group}` is not a standard global variable in EE2, so not a surprise that it doesn't work.

For a full list of Global Variables that work in EE2 see here:
https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/templates/globals/single_variables.html

HT